Can't run Windows WSL
Suddenly something must have changed on my machine so that WSL has stopped working. I even installed a new distro, it booted the first time and now it doesn't either. The moment I try to run any wsl command, it hangs:

What could I do to find out more? I have tried using the verbose mode, but it still hangs and I do not receive any information.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Kinda obvious WSL has stopped working, can you provide us the logs of the WSL if possible ?

Please see comment #2, as the OP stated reinstalling WSL resolved the issue

@JW0914 - The comment was already deleted. If the answer to the duplicate question resolves the author's question, then this question should be closed.
